# Count xml element under a element using Unix script

Tags: xml, unix

I have the following xml:

```
<Body>
<R1>
<T1> </T1>
<T1> </T1>
<T1> </T1>
</R1>
<R1>
<T1> </T1>
<T1> </T1>
<T1> </T1>
<T1> </T1>
</R1>
</Body>
```

I want the count of  element under each . How can get the same using Unix script. There can be more R1 elements in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an XML-aware tool. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) (a tool based on [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML) I happen to maintain), you can run

```
open file.xml ;
for /Body/R1 echo count(T1);
```